# MATLAB: Many matrix inversions faster

Tags: matlab, matrix-inverse

Suppose I have a multidimensional array X, whose size is A x A x B.
Here I assume B is as large as 100 or 1000, and A is small, such as 4 o r 8.
Then, I want calculate Y, whose size is the same as that of X, and
Y[:,:,b] = inv(X[:,:,b]), ***faster*** than I do with for-loop.
For example in Python, the package Numpy provides numpy.linalg.inv(), which can compute inverse matrix faster than naive for-loop (of course it is due to slowness of for-loop in Python).

```matlab
A = 4;
B = 1000;
X = rand(A, A, B);
Y = zeros(A, A, B);
for b = 1:B
    Y(:,:,b) = inv(X(:,:,b));
end

Z = ...             % somehow I want get this faster

sum(abs(Y(:)-Z(:))) % so that this is small enough
```

Comment: Why do you want it without a loop?

Comment: Actually for speed-up. I thought of hadamard product .* of matrices, which can be done faster with C.*D than the naive loop E(i,j)=C(i,j)*D(i,j). I want something similar, for matrix inversion, to calculate faster.

Comment: Consider changing the title from "without for-loop" to "faster". Is it faster in Python?

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, I changed the question statement. Actually in Python for-loop is pretty slow, so calculating matrix inversion without for-loop is so fast.

Comment: Now you question is too "old" to get noticed... I tried using `parfor` instead of `for`. In some cases it took halve the time, but there is a large overhead creating the parallel pool. In theory there is much room for speed up (like using C optimizations), but I couldn't find any practical solution.

Comment: Thanks Rotem, I'll give up accelerating matrix inversion.

Comment: I have the same problem. After about two weeks of searching I found no Matlab-native solution for handling tensors via vectorized operations. Your best bet is to switch to Numpy, which handles these things quite nicely.